# Information About method like Workbook_afterSave

Tags: excel, vba

I am Doing project using excel.

In Excel is there any method like `Workbook_afterSave` means if i change the cell value and save my workbook then according that cell value functions will be execute.

So anyone can suggest me method like `workbook_afterSave` in `ThisWorkbook` module?

Thanks In advance.

Comment: Your question is not clear - you want to use something **like** `Workbook_AfterSave` - but you don't explain why you can't use `Workbook_AfterSave`?

Comment: @YowE3K I guess, it's `Workbook_LikeAfterSave` :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using the [`Workbook_AfterSave` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-aftersave-event-excel):

```
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean) 
    If Success Then 
        MsgBox ("The workbook was successfully saved.") 
    End If 
End Sub
```

**Here's a list of [all Excel events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb267261(v=office.12).aspx).**

Comment: can we popup the messege box after the changing the value of cell with some content

Comment: That's a different question, but basically you could use the `Worksheet_Change` change event (which fires any time there is any change on the worksheet) and check `Target` to see if it's the cell or range that you're interested in.  There are a few things to consider when using an _on change_ event, so you'll want to do a bit of research and experiment with it on a backup copy. :-)

Comment: @JaydeepBobade Just remember that, if you change a cell **after** the save, you will need to save the workbook again to save the changed value, which will then run the `AfterSave` event again, which will change the cell, which means you will need to save the workbook again to save the changed cell ....